# How to get map widget for location selection with Location / GMap

Tags: 6, location, google-maps

I have GMap and Location modules set up and working. I have a working API key. The node with the location field can store long/lat or address data which I am using to populate a view. All of this works. The only problem I am facing is that I want the node creation form to use the GMap widget, so that users can click the map to populate the location field. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to enable this feature. I've checked everywhere that I can think of- any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure the answers below are good ones. However, due to the project constraints I need to get this working with the abovementioned modules. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the [Geolocation Field Module](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation)? It works with the Google Maps Api v3 and does exactly what you are trying to do. You add the map as a field/widget within your content-type. The Field stores lat/lon values.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of others who stumble on this question in future - If you are using a Drupal 7 site, then you can use Location and Gmap modules for this.

To allow picking of coordinates from a map you would have to edit the location module settings at `admin/config/content/location` and CHECK the option for using a google map as shown below

[image: using google maps for choosing coordinates using the location module]

Answer (score 0):

If you creating a service with maps and GeoTagFields, that you want to develop and improve in  future - you should to install Drupal 7.

1. Sooner or later you have to go to D7 - Do it right now!
2. There a lot of new [location modules](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:65%20drupal_core:103%20bs_project_sandbox:0&solrsort=sis_project_release_usage%20desc) for d7 which is unique and haven't versions for d6.
3. In August we expect в8 core and programmers instead of improving d6 versions of modules, will write new for d8.